# How to pass filtering parameters in PoweBI C# SDK

Tags: c#, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm generating Power BI embed token using C# SDK.

```
        using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(apiUrl), tokenCredentials))
        {
            var workspaceId = groupId.ToString(); 
            var report = await client.Reports.GetReportInGroupAsync(workspaceId, reportId);
            var generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "view");

            var tokenResponsex = await client.Reports.GenerateTokenAsync(workspaceId, reportId, generateTokenRequestParameters);

            result.EmbedToken = tokenResponsex;
            result.EmbedUrl = report.EmbedUrl;
            result.Id = report.Id;
        }
```

I need to pass a parameter for filtering. But couldn't find a straightforward way to do this. 
How do I get this done?

Comment: Generating access tokens has nothing to do with filtering the report. The [filters](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Filters) are added with [JavaScript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54098774/can-i-pass-a-dynamic-query-parameter-to-an-embedded-power-bi-report-in-asp-net-m/54104926#54104926), using the [Power BI JavaScript client](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript), in the report loader.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov I need to filter the data shown depending on the user who's accessing the report. Something like row level security. I'm very new to Power BI and don't know how to pass the RLS information here using the SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RLS in embedded reports implemented with app owns data scenario (a single master account for authentication) by passing [EffectiveIdentity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/reports_generatetokeningroup#effectiveidentity) information when generating access token for this report with [GenerateTokenInGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/reports_generatetokeningroup).

To implement RLS in the report itself you need either to [use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls#using-the-username-or-userprincipalname-dax-function) `USERPRINCIPALNAME()` [DAX function](https://dax.guide/userprincipalname/) to filter the data, or [define roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls#define-roles-and-rules-in-power-bi-desktop) and filter the data based on them. If you implement it with roles, after publishing the report go to dataset's security settings and add users to the roles.

To generate the token by providing an effective identity and roles membership, use code like this:

```
var credentials = new TokenCredentials(accessToken, "Bearer");

using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri("https://api.powerbi.com"), credentials))
{
    var datasets = new List<string>() { datasetId }; // Dataset's GUID as a string
    var roles = new List<string>();
    roles.Add('ROLE1');
    roles.Add('ROLE2');
    roles.Add('ROLE3');
    var effectiveIdentity = new EffectiveIdentity('user@example.com', datasets, roles);
    var r = new GenerateTokenRequest("view", effectiveIdentity);
    var token = client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroup(groupId, reportId, r).Token;
}
```